# Copy cell data from one worksheet to another worksheet only if both worksheets unique value matches

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, conditional-statements

I'm new to excel & i'm hating so much but it's uses are vast. Now for my query

- I've a workbook containing three sheets  'Project A' , 'Project B' & 'Project C'
- Project A  & Project B as same unique values but different descriptions
- Now using project A & Project B unique values the different descriptions should be display in seperate columns with its respective unique value project C. so total 3 columns in Project C.  This is my query?
- Can anyone point me out what formula to use or VBA or filter ? Help out this please.

Comment: Can edit your post and add a sample data and the expected results?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily with [XLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929) (Or with [VLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) if you're using an older version that doesn't support XLOOKUP).

On Project C, you should use the following in the column with the description you get from Project A:

```
=XLOOKUP($A2,'Project A'!$A:$A,'Project A'!$B:$B,"Not found")
```

Where: 
**$A2** is the reference for the unique value (Preferably within the same row of this cell); 
**'Project A'!$A:$A** is the range of the unique values' column on Project A sheet; 
**'Project A'!$B:$B** is the range of the descriptions' column on Project A sheet; 
**"Not found"** is the text that will appear if the unique value is not found on Project A. This is an optional field - you can leave it empty, so if the value won't be found a `#N/A` error will be the result of this function instead.

Another neater way of using the same function, is with **named ranges** - using Tables. Define the data tables on each of your sheets as Excel Tables by selecting them and pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or Insert -> Table.

Now, you can [rename each table](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/rename-an-excel-table-fbf49a4f-82a3-43eb-8ba2-44d21233b114) (let's say - tblProjectA is the name of the table in Project A) and use its name and its columns' header name in the function (let's say that the "unique value" column header is "ID", and "Description" is the header of the description column in tblProjectA):

```
=XLOOKUP([@ID],tblProjectA[ID],tblProjectA[Description],"Not found")
```

### Here's an example:

These are 3 sheets for example -

[image]
[image]
[image]

While this is the actual formulas written in Project C sheet:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my query

Comment: thank you for answering. Could you tell where I've to address project b sheet.  if project a unique values = project b unique values  matches then in project sheet c i should get matched values with descriptions.  I'm new to excel so could you provide more steps Please

Comment: I've added some screenshots of an example, hope it's more clear now. For help in  renaming the tables (which is a good practice) it will be best if you'll follow the steps given in the link I've posted (under the name "renaming each table"). And - if this answer helped, make sure to check it as solution by clicking the V on its left.